# TypeError: Redux Action is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was trying to dispatch a redux action(setMarker) into a component with mapDispatchToProps, but whenever I invoke that action I get this

> TypeError: setMarker is not a function

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { setMarker } from '../../redux/map/map.actions';

import './suggestion.styles.scss';

const Suggestion = (location, { setMarker }) => {
  const { area, city, address } = location;

  return (
    <div className="suggestion" onClick={() => console.log(setMarker)}>
      <i className="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-2x"></i>
      <div className="address">
        <h3 className="location-title">{`${area}, ${city}`}</h3>
        <p className="location-desc">{address}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setMarker,
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Suggestion);
```

My actions file contains the following code

```js
import mapActionTypes from './map.types';

export const setMarker = (location) => ({
  type: mapActionTypes.SET_MARKER,
  payload: location,
});
```

And my reducer file contains the following code

```js
import mapActionTypes from './map.types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  location: {
    lat: 23.810331,
    lng: 90.412521,
  },
};

const mapReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case mapActionTypes.SET_MARKER:
      return {
        ...state,
        location: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default mapReducer;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to import it like this: `{ setMarker }` so that it becomes a destructured prop

or you could do

`const Suggestion = (props) => {`

then call

`props.setMarker()`

also if you want another tip, you can do this for `mapDispatch` now

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    setMarker
}
```

much easier to read :)

Comment: can you `console.log(setMarker) ` what does it give you?

Comment: it says undefined :|

Comment: what have you changed from the feedback so far? can you update the code to the latest code?

Comment: can you try this? `({location, setMarker })` instead

Comment: You only get one `props` argument and you should destructure that. `{location, setMarker}`

Comment: I think you should do `(props)` then call `props.setMarker` and `props.location`

Comment: i did (props) and it now works and I get this after I console log the marker "() {
    return dispatch(actionCreator.apply(this, arguments));
  }"

Comment: the state is not updating, but i guess i can handle that now, thank you so much

Comment: no worries, let me know if you need more help in another question :)

Comment: @ShamimFahad are you able to accept the answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 2):

If `Suggestion` is a react component in the functional form then you would get props as an argument. You should use object destructuring syntax if you want to access them directly or you can use `props.setMarker`.

```
const Suggestion = ({location, setMarker}) => {
  const { area, city, address } = location;

  return (
    <div className="suggestion" onClick={() => setMarker(location)}>
      <i className="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-2x"></i>
      <div className="address">
        <h3 className="location-title">{`${area}, ${city}`}</h3>
        <p className="location-desc">{address}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is that error stemming from `mapDispatchToProps` or from inside the `onClick`? If the former is the case then check the import path.

Comment: import path is okay, i've also tried attaching a click handler but it had the same error there too, so, think it's inside the onClick function

Comment: Use `({location, setMarker})` not `(location, { setMarker })`

Comment: thank you, i destructured  (props) and it's working